# Is it possible to send "out of range" / "out of coverage area" signal if someone calls to my phone?

Tags: android

I want to develop an application that can give feeling to the caller that the called number is either switched off or out of coverage area. I am sure that it could be done at OS level but not sure if it can be done using the API provided. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for sending such messages to the telecom carrier using the public SDK, sorry.

Comment: any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: @sanjay I sincerely doubt you can, even from the OS level. Out of coverage signals don't really exist, for the simple reason that no device can send them successfully when needed, because when they're needed the device is already out of coverage. Carriers decide that a device is switched off/out of coverage when repeated attempts to connect to it timeout and fail.

Comment: when a carrier tries to connect a device (and it does through TCP/IP protocol), it sends a request to device and when device does not respond, carrier sends signal like out of coverage back to caller.  correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sanjay I'm not sure on the protocol, but otherwise you're correct.